# Social sharing issues: OG and title metas - WP

Tags: wordpress, redirect, social-media

I work with an organization that recently implemented CiviCRM on its WP site. Since then, social share information/open graph tags on certain pages are scraped from here: http://vector-space.org/civicrm/. The same is true for the title. When I checked FB's debugger, I realize processes a redirect and scrapes OG tags from the aforementioned page. For example, debugger results for an event:

> The following will be treated
>   as a redirect by the crawler:
>
> ```
> A HTTP redirect
> A <link rel="canonical" href=".." /> tag
> A <meta property="og:url" content=".." /> tag
> ```
>
> Wordpress SEO didn't resolve the issue since browsers/crawlers are
>   pointed to the CiviCRM header.

I found the parse code on the basepage template, but my coding skills are limited. Is there a way to resolve this so that we can display our own header/OG tags or Wordpress SEO OG info in social shares?

Thanks!

Comment: Note: I already reviewed this before posting. I can find the mentioned code, but my expertise ends there. : http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3335/how-do-i-get-pcps-to-look-right-when-shared-on-facebook

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the same behavior occurs on the official CiviCRM/WP demo site. The browser title for this demo page:
http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/info&reset=1&id=3

Does not match the generic title being scraped by FB:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

Meanwhile, the CiviCRM/Drupal demo site is scraped as one would hope:
http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/event/info?reset=1&id=3

Is this just a WordPress issue that is yet to be resolved?

Comment: The short answer is "yes". I started work on canonical URLs, but didn't get very far.