# How do we implement meta description, Open Graph, and Twitter Cards for CiviCRM in Joomla?

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, joomla, cms-integration

Although I am soliciting ways to accomplish these things now, this is more of a feature request, as I'm fairly certain from [other](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9568/social-sharing-issues-og-and-title-metas-wp) [posts](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3335/how-do-i-get-pcps-to-look-right-when-shared-on-facebook) that high quality metadata for CiviCRM output has not been a development priority yet.

To enhance CiviCRM's usefulness and adoption (and perhaps therefore the number of developers) the following features would be ideal:

1. Render proper meta descriptions specific to each page
2. Render proper Open Graph meta tags for each page
3. Render proper Twitter Card meta tags for each page
4. Create a field to identify a primary image to be used by the above tags, which will be necessary for:

   - Each event info page and registration page
   - The event listing page
   - Each contribution page
   - Any other public-facing landing pages
5. Properly implement SEO URL routing in Joomla (and Drupal and WordPress)
6. Render proper canonical URL link tag for each page

Some of the functionality for #2 and #3 could be hacked in using the CRM_Utils_System::addHTMLHead method, however the meta descriptions (#1) can't be updated this way because they've already been sent by the CMS. We'd need something like the CRM_Utils_System::setTitle method to override it.

I've hacked a solution for #5 and #6 by altering /CRM/Utils/System/Joomla.php to write pretty URLs and setting up .htaccess to untangle it back into the messy Joomla/CiviCRM hybrid URL, which itself seems to be a hack because it doesn't conform to the CMS's MVC method, which creates other problems (*bugs*) where Joomla doesn't properly understand which menu Itemid is supposed to be active.

To the dev team: Thank you for all your fantastic work on CiviCRM 4.7! It keeps getting better every time. I hope these enhancements will make CiviCRM even more viable for more organizations.

Thanks!

Comment: This seems like an excellent topic to raise on https://chat.civicrm.org in the ~dev channel and/or at https://lab.civicrm.org/development-team/features-requests.